# Bash if a variable is equal to true

Tags: bash

I want to check if the variable is equal to the true keyword and if it is then do something accordingly but it is behaving in an undefined way. don't get what I want its a simple question but thank you : >

```
STRICT=$false

if [ "$STRICT" == $true ] # i am not sure about this line what should i do
  then  
  FS="${FS} hey"
fi
```

Comment: Do you have variables named `true` and `false`?

Comment: There are no boolean keywords in shell. `$false` expands to the value of the (presumably undefined) variable `false`.

Comment: You might have a misunderstanding about `true` and `false` since you're calling it `keyword`. Consider taking a look at [this page about a **boolean**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type)

Comment: thanks everyoen i had know idea about that i could use true directly

Comment: You can use `true` directly because it's just a regular string. There is no boolean type in shell, and so no true and false values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use strings `true` and `false`, not variables.

```
STRICT=false

if [ "$STRICT" = true ]
then  
  FS="${FS} hey"
fi
```

And the standard string comparison operator is `=`. `==` is a `bash` extension.